# What is the story behind US senators wanting to "crack down on Bitcoin" in mid-2011?

Tags: history, legal, politics, usa

There have been two US senators, Charles Schumer and Joe Manchin, wanting to ["crack down on Bitcoin" in mid-2011](http://venturebeat.com/2011/06/08/government-crackdown-on-bitcoin/). How did the story start, progress and did it reach any conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some reports on Silk Road at the time, and they wanted action against Silk Road.